# Peers and Orderers: Phase 3 Of Ledger Update Process in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I was going through https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/peers/peers.html link where 3 phases of ledger updates have been discussed. My question is with regard to phase 3.We have below text at the above link:

After a peer has successfully validated each individual transaction, it updates the ledger.**Failed transactions are not applied to the ledger, but they are retained for audit purposes, as are successful transactions.**

Where are these failed transactions retained, are these with peer's FileSystem?

Are Failed and Invalidated transactions the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are appended to the block of the corresponding channel's chain, but they do not alter the channel's state.

With "failed" you probably refer to those transactions discarded by the chaincode's logic (those returning an HTTP 500 error on endorsement as launched by `shim.Error`).

With "invalidated" you probably refer to those transactions that do not fulfill the endorsement policy. For instance, individual endorsements return an HTTP 200 success code, but endorsements from different peers do not match. Another example: a `MVCC_READ_CONFLICT` error when trying to update the same writeset in the same block.

Comment: I understood failed and invalidated parts. with regards to point 1 do we have any documentation link as I tried finding out in fabric documents but could not find it. Please could you share it?

Comment: I learnt more from my experience than from the docs, but the general process is clearer from the transaction point of view than from the peer point of view: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/txflow.html

Comment: Yes, now I could figure blocks addition to the channel's chain part.